# how to write an array format

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, long-integer

I have declared this variable in class(something),
here is the code

```
long test[];
int year;
```

and I have declared a method(something) in class(something).
here is the code

```
public void something(long check[],int year) {
    for(int i=0;i<=1;i++){
    test[i]=check[i];
    }
    this.year=year;
}
```

and then in the main class,i tried to set the value of jumlah[] and tahun,
here is the code

```
something dood = new something();
dood.something("the error",2013);//error here
```

the error was

```
required: long[]
found: String
```

So, my question is, what is the right syntax do set the array values of `jumlah[]` or replacing "the error"?

I've tried `{123,321},[123,321],[{123,321}]` and it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe tell us which language ou are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`something` accepts an array of `long` as the first argument and an `int` as the second argument.
Your'e trying to pass to it a `String` and an `int`.

You should do something like that:

```
dood.something(new long[] { 1, 2, 3, 4}, 2014);
```

Comment: yes,i know.
i should put long[] and an int.
but,how to do it?